# override a void-method's content

Tags: testng, easymock

I'm using EasyMock 3+.

I'm testing a method e.g. `processMessage()`, which (would) meet my tests, but at the very end of the method this method also calls another method `dispatchMessage(String msg)` of the same class. That latter method takes on a @EJB injected object, which I really don't care about in this test. Of course - this object result in a NullPointerException.

How can I mock with Easymock this method to simply ignore it's code and return void. i.e.

```
void dispatchMessage(String msg){
     return;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to invoke `replay` or `verify`. I did it like this. Added the `@BeforeClass` annotation.

```
InboundMDB inboundMock;

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    inboundMock = new InboundMDB();
}
```

Then created an EasyMock builder instance and added the method I'm NOT interested in. Now, thi

```
IMockBuilder<InboundMDB> iMockBuilder = EasyMock
                .createMockBuilder(InboundMDB.class);
        inboundMock = iMockBuilder.addMockedMethod("dispatch")
                .createMock();
```

Following by this code, which invokes the method under test (original objective)...

```
try {
        inboundMock.processMessage(aMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Of course, if I omit the partial mock, it throws a null pointer exception as initially described. Now, it doesn't do so anymore. All good.

Comment: I encourage to use `replay` and `verify` to ensure that the mocked method is called as expected. Besides I think the `beforeClass` method is not necessary as you overwrite `inboundMock` later on anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the partial mock feature of EasyMock.

Let's assume the following class:

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

    @EJB
    private SomeEJB someEJB;

    public void processMessage() {
        dispatchMessage("some message");
    }

    public void dispatchMessage(String msg) {
        someEJB.dispatch(msg);        
    }
}
```

In order to test only the method `processMessage` you can mock `dispatchMessage`:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ProcessMessageTest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @Test
    public void processMessage() throws Exception {
        ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = createMockBuilder(ClassUnderTest.class)
            .addMockedMethod("dispatchMessage")
            .createMock();  
        classUnderTest.dispatchMessage("some message");
        replayAll();

        classUnderTest.processMessage();

        verifyAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot statically invoke the createMockBuilder method. It does not resolve the method. What library and library version are you using? imports?

Comment: EasyMock 3.3.1 was used in this example. I added a complete test class with imports to the answer. Additionally the example now makes use of `verifyAll` and `replayAll` (also found in `EasyMockSupport`).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the PowerMock framework which works very nicely with EasyMock and has some additional features you might find interesting (like mocking new object creations or static method calls): https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate

Answer (score 0):

for a mocking a void method, the `expectLastCall()` method is useful, and you do not need to return anything in this case as return type is void

essentially you need to do

```
mockObject.dispatchMessage(Easymock.anyObject(String.class));
Easymock.expectLastcall();
```

hope it helps!

good luck!